# Geoserver with Mapstraction

Tags: geoserver, wms, mapstraction

Do someone know how to use a custom hosted Geoserver's Tile Layers or WMS layers to be laid on Mapstraction as a base layer?

MapStraction has base layer plugins for google, yahoo, microsoft, openlayers etc., But unfortunately it lacks a plugin for custom open layers on geoserver. Do any one know how to neatly implement such a plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find how to do the above.

1. Made a Copy of mxn openlayers.
2. Changed the TMS url to WMS where the geoserver is hosted. There would be 2 urls of OSM and OSM Mapnik, kept only one of them and replaced with the WMS Url.
3. There was only one problem in calling toProperietory and fromProperietory calls. Did not honestly understand the logic, but replaced them with just returning same values

And it worked.

PS: If someone understands the logic behind step 3, please feel free to explain.